# Update dynamodb attribute with long data type using dynamodb mapper

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-mapper

I have a Java POJO for writing into dynamodb. The DynamoDB is being updated by 2 different AWS lambdas from 2 different AWS SQS. I am using dynamoDBMapper to save record into dynamodb. The mapper config looks like below

```
DynamoDBMapperConfig mapperConfig = DynamoDBMapperConfig.Builder().withSaveBehavior(DynamoDBMapperConfig.SaveBehavior.UPDATE_SKIP_NULL_ATTRIBUTES)
                .build();
```

I am using `UPDATE_SKIP_NULL_ATTRIBUTES` so that I don't have to provide all attributes while saving a record and the save() will not overwrite the existing record.

My POJO looks like

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "OrderShipment")
public class Order {
    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "id")
    @NonNull
    public String id;
    @DynamoDBRangeKey(attributeName = "sortKey")
    @NonNull
    public String sortKey;
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "createdDate")
    public long createdDate;
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "lastUpdated")
    public long lastUpdated;
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "status")
    public String status;
```

I am writing `createdDate` from one lambda and `lastUpdated,status` from second lambda using dynamodbMapper's save() API. To my surprise, the status field is not being overwritten, however createdDate and lastUpdated are being overwritten from the events and being set to 0. From my understanding `UPDATE_SKIP_NULL_ATTRIBUTES` should update the record and not overwrite the existing attributes in the record and it's working expected for `status`, but not for the long type. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

I did a silly mistake in `Order` POJO class. Instead of `Long`, I used the primitive data type `long`, which can not be null and hence it was initialized with 0 every time. I changed the data type for createdDate and lastUpdated to Long, it's working as expected.